# Minecraft development plugin for fabric mod not working

Tags: minecraft

I was trying to create a fabric mod for Minecraft using IntelliJ
I installed the Minecraft development plugin to make the setup process easier
but when I created a project it throwed errors. Pls help me counter this problem

Comment: What is your error ? and your logs ? Can you [edit] your post to add more details ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.